# Is there any way to show title only current date?

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

[image]

I want to show current date only at the title, not like the photo above.

```
themeSystem: 'standard',
            initialView: 'listWeek',
            headerToolbar: {
                start: 'prevYear,prev,today',
                center: 'title',
                end: 'timeGridWeek,listWeek,next,nextYear',
            },
```

My current code like that. Is there any way to custom the title? Thanks btw, hope you're doing good as well!

Comment: Please include the code you're using to render this Fullcalendar instance. A quick check of the Docs shows that you can modify the Format, like changing it to something like `October 9th to 15th, 2022`, etc, but not the actual content: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/titleFormat.

Comment: Sorry, I recently edit it. in headertoolbar center I only add 'title'. How should I do?

Comment: `'title'` is the key of the thing is is displayed in the "Center" of your toolbar. `start` (on the left) is those 3 buttons, `center` (in the middle) is the `'title'`, `end` (on the right) is those 4 buttons. Like I said, you can't change the content of the title, only the format. The title changes depending on the view, `timeGridWeek` shows Oct 9 - 15, 2022, `listWeek` would be different, but still dates, etc.

Comment: Alright, so how I change the format and apply  to my code?

Comment: Again... https://fullcalendar.io/docs/titleFormat - did you have a look in the documentation at all?

Comment: Yeah, read the documentation and apply it to your code. If you want it to say only `Oct 14, 2022` for the view that shows those dates, **you can't**. As I've said **three times now**, you can only change the format, but it will still show the range, unless you're on a view that only shows a single date.